# Why does Python's Decimal class generate additional digits that weren't there before?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

Take a look at the following outputs

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> print(2.4)
2.4

>>> print(Decimal(2.4))
2.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

Why exactly is this happening? If the explanation is that 2.4 couldn't be represented precisely, and therefore already had to be represented in approximate form, then how come the first print statement produced an exact result?

Comment: Don't use float literals if you expect precision. That's exactly what `Decimal` is for: it accepts numbers *as strings* to preserve absolute precision, but still allows you to do math with them.

Comment: It's not `Decimal`. The precision is lost the moment you gave the argument as a float. Give it as a string and see the difference.

Comment: "Why exactly is this happening?" Because it is giving you the decimal approximation of the binary floating point value you passed to it.

Comment: " then how come the first print statement produced an exact result?" it didn't. The value of 2.4 cannot be accutrately represented in binary. `float` objects just print an approximation (according to an algorithm that guarantees lossless roundtrip, and is the shortest)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This answered my question. If you post it, I would be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: …or just look at the list of duplicates above instead…

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Re “… it is giving you the decimal approximation of the binary floating point value…”: No, that is the exact value of the binary floating-point value, not an approximation.